# Existence theorems for self adjoint elliptic systems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities, elliptic-equations

Let's consider an elliptic (vectorial, homogeneous, constant coefficient) system of order 2m
$$
\begin{cases}
Lu=f &\text{in }\Omega\\
Bu=0 &\text{on }\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
which is **self adjoint**, meaning that
$$
\int_{\Omega}\langle Lu,v \rangle \mathrm{d}x=\int_{\Omega}\langle u,Lv\rangle\mathrm{d} x
$$
for all smooth $u,\,v$ that satisfy the boundary condition $Bu=0=Bv$.

My question is: where could I find satisfactory $L^2$-theory for such an elliptic boundary value problem, by which I mean that for each $f\in H^{-m}(\Omega)$ there exists a unique solution $u\in H^m(\Omega)$ with the estimate
$$
\|u\|_{H^m(\Omega)}\leq C\|f\|_{H^{-m}(\Omega)}?
$$

Equivalently, does anyone know whether the Lopatinskii--Shapiro conditions are satisfied for fully self adjoint elliptic problems?

(Almost) equivalently, does anyone know whether the a priori estimate
$$
\|u\|_{H^m(\Omega)}\leq C\|Lu\|_{H^{-m}(\Omega)}
$$
holds for smooth fields satisfying $Bu=0$?

*Other details/assumptions*: I am happy to assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a bounded and smooth domain. By elliptic operator/system above I mean 
$$
(Lu)_j=\sum_{|\alpha|=2m} \langle L_{j}^\alpha, \partial^\alpha u\rangle,\quad u\colon\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R^N
$$
for $L_j^\alpha\in\mathbb R^{N}$, $j=1\ldots N$, which is such that the (symmetric) matrix defined by
$$
L(\xi)_j=\sum_{|\alpha|=2m} L_{j}^\alpha \xi^\alpha\in\mathbb R^{N},\quad \xi\in\mathbb R^n
$$
is strictly positive definite for all $\xi\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$. Equivalently,
$$
\langle u_0, L(\xi)u_0\rangle\geq C|\xi|^{2m}|u_0|^2,\quad u_0\in\mathbb R^N,\,\xi\in\mathbb R^n,
$$
or equivalently 
$$
\det L(\xi)\neq0,\quad\text{for all }\xi\in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}.
$$
Finally, I can add more assumptions on $L$, so please let me know if you know more restrictive statements.

Thank you!